# How to use right click on Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m using iOS client with a NukkitX server where I installed FAWE plugin. Selection like `//sel cuboid` requires left and right click. How can I do that with Pocket edition? It seemes that this is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Just tap an interactable for a few seconds. For example, if you long press a llama, you will automatically be mounted on the llama and will not have to tap the 'mount' button at the bottom of the screen to get on. Do not short press as you will be punching it.